# Computing the "closure" of the attributes of an object given functions that change the attributes

Tags: python, oop, object, functional-programming, state

I have an object `obj` and a number of functions

```
    def func1(obj):
    #...

    def func2(obj):
    #...

    def func3(obj):
    #...
```

that each change the values of the attributes of `obj`.

I want my input to be something like

```
obj = MyObject()
obj.attr=22
```

This should be passed to a function `closure()` that computes all possible applictions of the functions above, meaning `func1(func2(obj))`, `func3(func1(func1(obj)))` etc. up to a certain stopping condition (e.g. no more than 20 function compositions).

The output should be a list of all possible outputs together with all paths leading there. So if, say `104` and `93` are the one possible final outputs if `obj.attr=22`, and there are two ways to arrive at `104` and one to arrive at `93`. Then

```
print closure(obj)
```

should be something like

```
[22, 64, 21, 104] #first path to 104 through , func1(obj),func1(func1(obj)), func1(func1(func3(obj)))

[22, 73, 104] #second path to 104 through , func3(obj),func3(func2(obj)), 

[22, 11, 93] #the only path to arrive at 94
```

How could I implement this? As was suggested in the comments, this is best done with trees, but although I tried 2 days I almost didn't make any progress implementing that (I'm new to Python/programming)!
My example is so simple that instead of `func(obj)` we could directly use `func(22)` but the example I need to work on is more complicated, where I definitely will need to use objects, so this would only be a minimal working example for that.

The tree will probably not be a full n-ary tree, since each function application will contain a test whether it can be applied to the current state (of the attributes) of `obj` and in some cases the test will fail leaving (the attributes of) `obj` unchanged.

Comment: Seems like you want a tree structure where each node is a state and the branching happens by the functions (each function takes a state and creates a **new** node/state). This is common practice in AI and other fields and could be useful here. To trace what happened just traverse back to the root once you've reached the required state. Oh, and make it BFS if possible :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yes, that seems what I want I think, thx. But why use BFS though?

Comment: Well, if you use DFS and you have an infinite application path of functions... You're not going to ever find anything meaningful even if there is a "solution". However, if there is a solution, DFS guarantees to find it (but you pay in memory, unlike DFS which is constant memory).

You can also use iterative DFS (google it) to guarantee it halts.

Comment: DFS guaranteed = BFS guarantees * :)

Comment: What should the final output be? A list of all possible outputs? A path to get to the desired output? Does this path need to contain the minimum number of functions?

Comment: @user3080953 Please see my edit.

Comment: please post the input and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example that tries to find whether a number (`goal`) is a predecessor
of another (`inital_state`) when applying the rule in the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

In your example, `obj` is the `state`, and `[func1, func2, ...]` is `functions` in my example.
This version will return a path to a final output, minimizing the number of function applications.
Instead of searching, you can list all states by removing the goal test and returning `prev_states` after the loop finishes.

```
from collections import deque

def multiply_by_two(x):
    return x * 2

def sub_one_div_three(x):
    if (x - 1) % 3 == 0:
        return (x - 1) // 3
    else:
        return None # invalid


functions = [multiply_by_two, sub_one_div_three]

# find the path to a given function
def bfs(initial_state, goal):
    initial_path = []
    states = deque([(initial_state, initial_path)])     # deque of 2-tuples: (state, list of functions to get there)
    prev_states = {initial_state}                       # keep track of previously visited states to avoid infinite loop

    while states:
        # print(list(map(lambda x: x[0], states)))      # print the states, not the paths. useful to see what's going on
        state, path = states.popleft()

        for func in functions:
            new_state = func(state)

            if new_state == goal:                       # goal test: if we found the state, we're done
                return new_state, path + [func]

            if (new_state is not None and           # check that state is valid
                new_state not in prev_states):      # and that state hasn't been visited already
                states.append((new_state, path + [func]))
            prev_states.add(new_state)              # make sure state won't be added again
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not get to state")

print(functions)
print(bfs(1, 5))

# prints (5, [<function multiply_by_two at 0x000002E746727F28>, <function multiply_by_two at 0x000002E746727F28>, <function multiply_by_two at 0x000002E746727F28>, <function multiply_by_two at 0x000002E746727F28>, <function sub_one_div_three at 0x000002E7493C9400>]). You can extract the path from here.
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to understand the code (pls bear with me, since I'm a beginner), so that I can adapt it to my own needs. It seems that your bfs function does not just compute the bfs of a given graph, but directly also creates the graph, right? Is this the standard design choice, or would a possibility be also to first create separately a tree class/object where each node is a list of the form `func3(func1(func(2(...))))` and then use a bfs to traverse it? At least conceptually that is how I would have done it.

Comment: You're right, I'm not explicitly computing the graph/ tree. If you need to perform more operations on the graph, it would make sense to cache it, but if this is the only operation you need, there's no reason to build it explicitly

Comment: I saw your edit about using objects instead of ints. To fix that, you need to make your state hashable (implement `__hash__`) and make `func(state)` return an object, not modify `state`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fun, let's break it down to steps.

1. Figure out possible combinations of functions.
2. Evaluate possible combinations of functions.

**Figuring out possible combinations**

One way to do this is using generators. They're efficient in terms of memory, so you don't end up creating a bunch of values and maxing out the heap.

So how do we get all the combinations. A quick search of Python docs suggests using itertools. So let's do that.

```
from itertools import combinations

def comb(fns, n):
     return combinations(fns, n)
```

So far we have a generator that can give us all the combinations (without replacement) of a list of functions. Each provided combination would be a list of functions `n` large. We can simply call each in turn and we can get the composed result.

That's one level in the tree. How do we get the next level. Well, we could get all combinations of size 1 and then all combinations of size 2 and so on. Since generators are lazy, we aught to be able to do this without blowing up the interpretor.

```
def combo_tot(fns):
    start=1
    while (start <= len(fns)):
        for c in comb(fns, start):
            yield c
        start += 1
```

**Evaluating possible combinations**

So now we have all the possible combinations that make sense. Let's use this to evaluate stuff.

```
def evalf(fns_to_compose, initval):
    v = initval
    for fn in fns_to_compose:
        v = fn(v)
    return v
```

So thats part two. Now all you need to do is chain em.

```
def results(fns, init):
    return (evalf(fn, init) for fn in combo_tot(fns))
```

Now just take as many results as you need.

**Downside**

Same as with any method that doesn't clone the `obj`. It's going to mutate the object. Moreover, we have the overhead of generators (which can be slightly slower than for-loops). We also have a hit to readability (especially if someone isn't familiar with generators).

Disclaimer: I'm typing this on a phone. Minor typos etc might exist.